# jQuery post to PHP not working without any errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery dialog button, and inside it I parse all the inputs.

I want to send these parsed values to a php file, but when I click "OK" nothing happens -at all-, without any errors.

Here's my code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: [ {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    var functionName = $("#txtFunctionName").val();
                    var cassName = $("#txtClassName").val();
                    var classDesc = $("#txtClassDesc").val();
                    var input = $("#txtInput").val();
                    var output = $("#txtOutput").val();


                    /* SEND THE DATA TO addFunc.php */
                    var $dataStr = {'name': functionName,
                                     'input': input,
                                     'output': output,
                                     'class': cassName,
                                     'desc': classDesc};
                    $.post('../php/addFunc.php', 
                                     $data,
                                     function(response){
                                         alert("test");
                                         }

                                     );


                    $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    } 
                }]  
        });
```

And the `addFunc.php` contains just a sample echo to verify correctness, but it doesn't alert anything, meaning it didn't work:

```
<?php
echo "Welcome";
?>
```

Comment: addFunc.php? Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, you're sending `$data` to the php and not `$dataStr`, which `$data` is not set.

Comment: No, not a typo, only a typo here and not in the actual code/filename.

Comment: Changed `$data` to `$dataStr`, it still does nothing!

Comment: get rid of the single quotes in the identifiers for the array $dataStr

Comment: Done but still no luck :/

Comment: And nothing appears in your console?

Comment: try to use ./ in url instead of ../ I think you have a problem with connecting with php file  .. and do like @MiiinimalLogic said

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef fix worked! Oh my god.

Comment: Make somethink like *$(document).ajaxError(function( event,request,settings){alert( "Error " + settings.url);});* to handle the ajax error (more information in https://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

Comment: Can you check your browser network panel and see if it's making a request to that file at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$dataStr` to `dataStr` and add the correct var (dataStr no $data) in the post function.

Try this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            buttons: [ {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function() {
                    var functionName = $("#txtFunctionName").val();
                    var cassName = $("#txtClassName").val();
                    var classDesc = $("#txtClassDesc").val();
                    var input = $("#txtInput").val();
                    var output = $("#txtOutput").val();


                    /* SEND THE DATA TO addFunc.php */
                    var dataStr = {'name': functionName,
                                     'input': input,
                                     'output': output,
                                     'class': cassName,
                                     'desc': classDesc};
                    $.post('../php/addFunc.php', 
                                     dataStr,
                                     function(response){
                                         alert("test");
                                         }

                                     );


                    $( this ).dialog( "close" ); 
                    } 
                }]  
        });
```